# SharePoint 2013 Built-in App Calendar: People Picker - Autocomplete & Saves

Tags: sharepoint-designer, form, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

Can the built-in Calendar App on Sharepoint 2013 On-premise "Attendees" column people picker be changed to autocomplete/people suggestion on the forms? This app is preferred over creating a custom list and creating a calendar view.

Changed `<SharePoint:FormField` to `<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker` but saving the event does not actually save the name(s) in the "Attendees" column list.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a new Person/Group column on your Calendar list, and then update the "Event" content type of the Calendar to include your newly created column, and remove the existing attendees column. The new field will be of type client picker.

Comment: Added a new people/group column to the calendar list and is visible in New Form but isn't auto-complete.

Comment: Is it behaving the same exact way as the existing Attendees field? Also can you post a screenshot of what the new field looks like?

Comment: Yes, behaving the same way as the existing Attendees field. Added new people/group column to Calendar list > New Form displays
http://i.stack.imgur.com/8t36N.png

Comment: I think this might be your solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/25530379/5878778

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha, I've seen this before and I've changed the old control to the new but I'm not exactly sure what to do next. I don't know much of the code and this is something I haven't done before. Would it be possible for you to explain step by step? I'm not sure what to change if anything needs to be changed and what part to insert if any of it needs to be insert while editing the form. I appreciate the help!

Comment: let me get something straight. So after changing from FormField to ClientPicker your attendees field is autocompleting but the resulting person is not saved in the column once you save the item?

Comment: That is correct. I changed FromField to ClientPeoplePicker and the form is auto-completing the way that I want but when I click save and view the list the column is blank. The field is also empty when I edit the item.

Comment: Got it and it looks like a Sharepoint limitation on custom aspx forms. Someone suggested a workaround of having a hidden regular people picker to which the client picker value would get copied to on Save, and then retrieved from onload. This way your column will have the information in it. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111160/clientpeoplepicker-control-in-custom-sharepoint-list-form

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I think I followed what Alexandar did but I could not get the clientpeoplepicker list to copy over to the 2010 peoplepicker.